# How to split record from a DataFrame cross pairs in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I hava a dataframe like this :

```
   a  b  c
0  A  B  1
4  B  A  1
1  C  D -1
3  D  C  3
2  E  F  3
```

The '0' row and '4'row are a pair, I will remove one row by the value of 'c' columns. According to 'c' columns, I decide to remove which one or remove all of them. If mirror pair have same value in `c` column, I will remove one row, or I will remove all of them.

```
   a  b  c
0  A  B  1
2  E  F  3
```

I use while, but my data set is huge. Have any good ideas ?

Comment: What exactly is column `c` telling us here? It would be useful if you provided some expected output with different values for column `c`.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC using `np.sort` with `duplicated`

```
df1=df.loc[~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['a','b']].values,axis=1)).duplicated().values]
   a  b  c
0  A  B  1
1  C  D -1
2  E  F  3
```

Comment: the `0` row and `4` row have same value in `c` column so I want to remove one of them, while `1` row and `3`row have different value, I want to remove all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `agg` with frozenset and `duplicated` and slicing

```
s = df[['a', 'b']].agg(frozenset, axis=1)
m = ~s.duplicated(keep=False) | (s.duplicated(keep=False) & df.c.duplicated())

df.loc[m]

Out[165]:
   a  b  c
4  B  A  1
2  E  F  3
```

Comment: There are some problems. In the `c` column, if there are many `1` or other number, there will be a incorrect filter. In the `c` column, there are only three number, they are `1`, `-1` and `3`.

Answer (score 1):

first select the non-duplicated rows using `np.sort` and [`Series.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) (see **m1** detail)

Then you can use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)
and group according to columns `a, b` (see detail **g**). Then perform a [`Boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) using [`Groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) to eliminate duplicates when c does not match.:

```
df2=df.reset_index(drop=True)
m1=~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df2[['a','b']])).duplicated()
g=m1.cumsum()
m2=~df2.groupby(g,sort=False)['c'].transform(lambda x: (x.nunique()==len(x))&(len(x)>1))
mask=m1&m2
print(mask)

0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

---

```
df_filtered=df2[mask]
print(df_filtered)

   a  b  c
0  A  B  1
4  E  F  3
```

---

**Details:**

```
m1
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

---

```
m2
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

---

```
g

0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    3
dtype: int64
```